# event.preventDefault and jasmine.toHaveBeenTriggeredOn do not work together

Tags: javascript, events, testing, jasmine, preventdefault

I have an object with a click listener and try to write tests for it. I have problems using jasmine `expect(event).toHaveBeenTriggered()` and it seems the problem is the `e.preventDefault` statement.

Listener:

```
$(document).on("click", "input", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do something
});
```

Test:

```
describe("SomeTest", function () {
    "use strict";

    beforeEach(function () {
        setFixtures("<input />");
    });

    it("should have been triggered", function () {
        var input = $('input');
        var spyEvent = spyOnEvent(input, 'click' );
        $( input ).click();
        expect( spyEvent ).toHaveBeenTriggered();
    });

});
```

Is there a way to get `toHaveBeenTriggered` to work or disable `preventDefault` for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are special `Matcher`s in [`jasmine-jquery`](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) for this `toHaveBeenPreventedOn()` and `toHaveBeenPrevented()`

From the [documentation](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#event-spies):

```
var spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#some_element', 'click')
$('#some_element').click(function (event){event.preventDefault();})
$('#some_element').click()
expect('click').toHaveBeenPreventedOn('#some_element')
expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenPrevented()
```